# 'unexpected indent' in python

Tags: python, directory

I am making a program in python where I read a filepath, put different pieces of that path in variables, change the path and make a new dir with that path. Everything almost seems to work. But at the end when I try to create the new dirs I am getting 'unexpected indent' error on

```
newFilePath.mkdir(parents=True)
```

I can't seem to find the problem.

```
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path


root = "C:\Voorleessoftware\\"
path = os.path.join(root, "targetdirectory")

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        filePath = str(os.path.join(path, name))
        #filepath voorbeeld = c:\Voorleessoftware\1 sept\10u30\1e graad\1A1\test.txt
        
        findchar1 = '\\'
        list = [pos for pos, char in enumerate(filePath) if char == findchar1]
        rootDir   = filePath[0:list[0]]
        standaard = filePath[list[0]:list[1]]
        dag       = filePath[list[1]:list[2]]
        uur       = filePath[list[2]:list[3]]
        graad     = filePath[list[3]:list[4]]
        klas      = filePath[list[4]:list[5]]
        bestand   = filePath[list[5]:len(filePath)-1]
        
        #nieuwe filepath 
        newFilePath = rootDir + standaard + dag + graad + klas + uur + bestand

        # Dirs aanmaken nieuw filepath
        newFilePath.mkdir(parents=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You just need to add a newline(cursor should be at the beginning of the line) after `newFilePath.mkdir(parents=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no indentation between

```
newFilePath = rootDir + standaard + dag + graad + klas + uur + bestand
```

and

```
# Dirs aanmaken nieuw filepath
newFilePath.mkdir(parents=True)
```

Which means your two `for` blocks are interpreted as ending after the former, which in turn means that your indentations for the last line are unexpected. To see the difference, try marking (with your cursor) the empty line before the `#nieuwe filepath`, and then also the empty line before the `# Dirs aanmaken nieuw filepath` – you'll see the difference.

Comment: Thanks this helped alot :) Problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

it should be either this
`root = "C:\Voorleessoftware\"`
or this `root = "C:\\Voorleessoftware\\"`

always use `\\` to represent path in windows

thank you

Comment: Note that `root = "C:\Voorleessoftware\"` will not work: the last backslash escapes the `"` which should be invalid syntax. I do agree that using \\ is strongly preferable: in the case of a capital V like here, the backslash would be interpreted as \\, if I'm not mistaken, because `\V` is not a special character – but this is just happenstance: if the word started with an `n`, for instance, for example in the case of `root = "C:\nice\\"`, then rather than backslash-followed-by-n we'd have a newline character.

Comment: yea it consider it as a ```escape sequence```.

Comment: Note that this doesn't answer the question at all. But if you have to mention it: Why not mention raw strings? That's exactly what they are there for!

Comment: look at is ```root``` variable, you can't use raw string with incorrect structure